# Complex Matrix Inversion in OpenCL

Tags: matrix, opencl, inversion

Is there any way to invert a complex Matrix with openCL?

Comment: Sure - why not - what have you tried and what specific problem are you encountering ?

Comment: Originally I wanted to do it with viennaCL lu_factorize and lu_substitute but viennaCL doesn't have a complex type. So can I part my matrix into real an imaginary matrices and compute them somehow seperate?

Answer (score -1):

To my knowledge, there is no library yet to do this.  MAGMA and ViennaCL both seem on track to build this though.  Perhaps CULA will come out with an OpenCL version too...